# Woo commerce product page changed layout

Tags: woocommerce

I do sell downloadable products, I dont know what changed that I cannot see the downloadable option when i want to upload a new product. The layout looks to have changed. anyone there who can assist in restoring the product page. see the screen shot of what am getting now

Comment: The screen shot you are talking about seems missing? also go through [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) when adjusting your question, so that all conditions are met to be able to ask a good question. Regards

Comment: Please provide a URL, too. Currently, your question is impossible to answer.